# Test signal with my own class

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qsignalspy

I have some class which can emit some signal with another my class. Example:

```
class CMyClass : public QBytaArray
{
    void SomeAction();
}

class CMainClass : public QObject
{
    signals:
        void testSignal(const CMyClass &myClass);

    public:
        void test() {
          CMyClass data;  
          emit testSignal(data);
        }
}
```

I wrote unix test for CMainClass:

header:

```
#ifndef TESTMAINCLASS_H
#define TESTMAINCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSignalSpy>

#include "MainClass.h"

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CMyClass)

class CTestMainClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit CTestMainClass(QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
  void testS();
};

#endif // TESTMAINCLASS_H
```

Source:

```
#include <QDebug>

#include "TestMainClass.h"

CTestMainClass::CTestMainClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  qRegisterMetaType<CMyClass>();
}

void CTestMainClass::testS()
{
  qDebug() << "Test signal emitor";
  CMainClass prc;

  QSignalSpy spy(&prc, SIGNAL(testSignal(const CMyClass&)));
  prc.test();


  CMyClass buf = qvariant_cast<CMyClass>(spy.at(0).at(0));

}
```

But, in log file I've got:

> PASS   : CTestCommandProcessor::initTestCase() QDEBUG :
>   CTestCommandProcessor::testS() Test signal emitor QDEBUG :
>   CTestCommandProcessor::testS() Count:  1 QDEBUG :
>   CTestCommandProcessor::testS() Vals:  QVariant(CMyClass, ) A crash
>   occurred in
>   C:\UnitTest\build-UnitTest-Qt_5_7_1_5_7_1_Static-Release\release\UnitTest.exe.
>   Function time: 0ms Total time: 0ms

I've tried to change string:

> CMyClass buf = qvariant_cast< CMyClass >(spy.at(0).at(0));

to

> CMyClass buf = qvariant_cast< const CMyClass& >(spy.at(0).at(0));

But, I was getting the same error.
What is wrong? Can I use in Qt's unittest signals with my own classes?

Comment: Can you post the full code?
You are calling `test()` on your `CMyClass` in your example, but `CMyClass` has no such method.

Also, the 2 lines you pasted: `CMyClass buf = qvariant_cast(spy.at(0).at(0));` are the exact same.

Comment: Sorry. Posted full code.

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: How can I get stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sory, this is my bad. 
I used takeFirst() method of spy. And after that spy's object doesn't have signals anymore.